# Writing to csv a dictionary with datetime.datetime object as keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dictionary which contains `datetime.datetime` objects as keys and I would like to write them to a csv file. However, the error below is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Documents/08_PYTHON/00_PROJECTS/Navps/code/scrape.py", line 179, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 147, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Here is my code below:

```
csv_columns = ['Date','Fund Value']
try:
    with open(bof, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in csvdict:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Here is what `csvdict` looks like:

```
csvdict = {datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 16, 0, 0): '2.8010', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8, 0, 0): '2.8295', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0): '2.8326',....}
```

Is there something I'm missing when handling `datetime.datetime` objects as keys? I really want to have dates as my keys. Is this not at all possible?

Note: If it helps I am running it this script on Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `csv.DictWriter` wants each row to be a dictionary. So, to use it you need to convert the pairs of key, value items in the `csvdict` into a rows. That's easy with built-in `zip()` function:

```
import csv
import datetime


bof = 'bof.csv'
csvdict = {datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 16, 0, 0): '2.8010',
           datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8, 0, 0): '2.8295',
           datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0): '2.8326',}

csv_columns = ['Date','Fund Value']
try:
    with open(bof, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in (dict(zip(csv_columns, item)) for item in csvdict.items()):
            writer.writerow(row)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Comment: But i don't understand: isn't `data` in `writer.writerow(data)` a dictionary in itself, since data is basically a single dictionary element in a list of dictionaries `csvdict`?

Comment: Nico: `csvdict` is a dictionary of key, value pairs (as they always are). The code in my answer converts each of those into a separate dictionaries in the proper format to pass to `writerow()`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding how `DictWriter` works; the [example](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#//apple_ref/Class/csv.DictWriter) says you'd write in full dicts, e.g.

```
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

and what you have is one big key-value dictionary. It'd be better to use a plain `csv.Writer`:

```
csv_columns = ['Date','Fund Value']
with open(bof, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.Writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(csv_columns)
    for date, value in csvdict.items():
        writer.writerow([date.isoformat(), value])
```

I've gone ahead and chosen ISO-8601 as the date format for you, [because it's the only right thing to do ;-)](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: But i don't understand: isn't `data` in `writer.writerow(data)` a dictionary in itself, since data is basically a single dictionary element in a list of dictionaries `csvdict`?

Comment: No, your `csvdict` is a single dictionary with datetimes for keys and strings for values, not a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

DictWriter is for writing a list of dictionaries:

- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter for examples

that contain the exact same keys.

You can use a normal csv-writer:

```
import datetime
import csv

bof = "somefile.csv"
csvdict = {datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 16, 0, 0): '2.8010', 
           datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8, 0, 0): '2.8295',
           datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0): '2.8326'}
csv_columns = ['Date','Fund Value']
try:
    with open(bof, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(csv_columns)
        for key, value in csvdict.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Output:

> ```
> Date,Fund Value
> 2019-01-16 00:00:00,2.8010
> 2019-02-08 00:00:00,2.8295
> 2019-02-07 00:00:00,2.8326
> ```

Comment: It's more idiomatic (and faster) to do `for p, v in csvdict.items()` than access the dict separately to get the value.